# How to check propertychanged only once in each Timer tick?

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services, inotifypropertychanged, polling

I use 2 Timers, 1 Check all my Citect tags for changed values each second. The other one is a KeepAlive Timer for a TCP Connection.

This is how i call the Timers:

```cs
Timer timer = new Timer(ctApiCtrl.CheckUpdateAllInputTags, "updatetags", 1000, 1000);
Timer timer2 = new Timer(mepCtrl.KeepAlive, "test", 3000, 3000);
```

Now due the nature of how the existing systems works together is with writing and reading PLC/DSK tags. So if my service wants to detect these changes it needs to periodically "poll" or check these values.

This is the class where those tags comes from:

```cs
        public class TagWithValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public string  TagName { get; set; }
            private string tagValue;
            public TagCategory TagCategory { get; set; }
            public string TagValue
            {
                
                get { return tagValue; }
                set 
                { 
                    if(tagValue != value)
                    {
                        tagValue = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "") 
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
```

So when the property `TagValue` changes it detects it and fire x.

```cs
        public void CheckUpdateAllInputTags(object objectInfo)
        {
            VDGSenseController.Authenticate();
            if (listOfTags.Video == null || listOfTags.Audio == null)
            {
                Logger.Info("Empty Tag list , reinitliazing all tags");
                InitiliazeAllTags();
            }
            
            foreach (var tag in Tags)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = TagRead(tag.TagName); //read Tag value
                    tag.TagValue = value;
                    tag.PropertyChanged += d_PropertyChanged;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Warn(ex,"Importing tag unsuccesfull");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            Tags = Tags.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.TagValue)).Distinct().ToList();
        }
```

Here lies the problem of this snippet.

```cs
private void d_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{           
     //trigger wanneer prop value is changed
     var tagchanged = (CtModel.TagWithValue)sender;
            
    Logger.Info($"Tag: {tagchanged.TagName} with value: {tagchanged.TagValue} has changed.");
}
```

The problem i have with this code is that it fires multiple times the propertychanged method in the same timer tick.

**Note the logging that contains Tag: DK_OM_2A**

[image: timer logging]

How can i change this so it only fires once each timer tick?

Comment: There are missing parts of code to be able to answer your question, it is possible to call more than once for the same tag the tag.PropertyChanged += d_PropertyChanged; so you subscribe more than once to the event for each property change (consider tag.PropertyChanged -= d_PropertyChanged; before adding it again)

Comment: I added the method that the timer calls. Where should i put tag.PropertyChanged -= d_PropertyChanged?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by moving the logic from the propertychanged in a different method and in the new code it goes like this:

```
    private void d_PropertyChanged(object sender,PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
        //trigger wanneer prop value is changed
        var tagchanged = (CtModel.TagWithValue)sender;
        tagsWithChangedValue.Add(tagchanged);
        tagsWithChangedValue = tagsWithChangedValue.Distinct().ToList();

    }


#region UpdateTagsPropertyChanged
    public void UpdateTagsPropertyChanged(List<CtModel.TagWithValue> listofchangedtags)
    {
        if(listofchangedtags.Count == 0)
        {
            return; // if list is empty, go back
        }
        foreach(var tagchanged in listofchangedtags)
        {
            logger.Info($"Tag: {tagchanged.TagName} with value: {tagchanged.TagValue} has changed.");
            switch (tagchanged.TagName)
            {
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        tagsWithChangedValue.Clear(); //clears list for the next cycle
    }
    #endregion
```